# creating a new dataframe with pd.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, where-clause

I have a dataframe named History and I am trying to create a new dataframe named current_hist from History. My condition for this new frame is where C == 1 create a new dataframe (current_hist) with the columns: ID, Date, U. can I use pd.where to do this or is there a better way

Comment: please add some more information or at least an exemple

Comment: Provide some code with a clear question.

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is `new_df = df[df["C"] == 1]["ID", "Date", "U"]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.